# Freed memory not causing page fault

Tags: c, windows, winapi, virtual-memory

In experimenting with reserving and committing virtual memory to a process, I allocated 64K bytes of memory with `VirtualAlloc`, `memcpy`'d a test string into it, `printf`'d it like a string, freed the memory with `VirtualFree` with the `MEM_RELEASE` flag, and `printf`'d it again. For some reason, no page fault is triggered. Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

INT main(DWORD argc, LPSTR argv[]) {
    SYSTEM_INFO info;
    DWORD dwPageSize;
    DWORD dwMemSize;
    LPVOID lpvMem;

    GetSystemInfo(&info);
    dwPageSize = info.dwPageSize;
    dwMemSize = 16 * dwPageSize;

    lpvMem = VirtualAlloc((LPVOID) 0x00F00000, dwMemSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!lpvMem) {
        printf("Error allocating virtual memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("lpvMem = 0x%08X\n", (UINT32) (UINT64) lpvMem);

    if (!memcpy(lpvMem, "I love foxes \\(^o^)/", 21)) {
        printf("Error copying memory (error code 0x%08X)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Before free: %s\n", (LPCSTR) lpvMem);
    VirtualFree(lpvMem, dwMemSize, MEM_RELEASE);
    printf("After free:  %s\n", (LPCSTR) lpvMem);

    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
lpvPagedMemory = 0x00F00000
Before free: I love foxes \(^o^)/
After free:  I love foxes \(^o^)/
```

Comment: No where is it defined that accessing freed memory will cause a page fault. It *may* cause a page fault. But that's not a certainty. In C this is called Undefined Behaviour. Any code that has UB is considered to be buggy (even if some runs of the program do not exhibit obvious "bad" behaviour).This question has more details: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: VirtualFree(lpvMem, 0, MEM_RELEASE); - this is correct code. VirtualFree(lpvMem, dwMemSize, MEM_RELEASE); - error - "If the dwFreeType parameter is MEM_RELEASE, this parameter must be 0"

Comment: @kaylum It is a defined certainty **on Windows**. C does not define it but Windows does.

Comment: @user3386109 - here nothing common with "Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?". here simply error by VirtualFree api call with wrong second parameter - must be 0

Comment: Voting to reopen as this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line:

```
VirtualFree(lpvMem, dwMemSize, MEM_RELEASE);
```

is an error.  You are not checking what [`VirtualFree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892.aspx) returns, and the documentation says:

> dwSize [in]
>   ...
>   If the dwFreeType parameter is MEM_RELEASE, **this parameter must be 0
>   (zero)**. The function frees the entire region that is reserved in the initial allocation call to VirtualAlloc.

So you need to use this instead:

```
VirtualFree(lpvMem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
```

About the page fault - it can (and must) only happen after a *successful* call to `VirtualFree()`.